# HTMLUNIT not loading HTTPS webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, https, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to load an HTTPS URL which works fine with the `FirefoxDriver`, but when I use HTMLUNIT Driver, I'm getting below error when trying to access the first element on the webpage.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

When I use `webDriver.getCurrentUrl()`, I got the page URL saying "about:blank" and `webDriver.getPageSource()` produces empty HTML content (with HTMLUNIT). I have done a lot of extensive research into this and have already tried these suggested techniques:

- HTMLUNIT with no proxy
- webClient.getOptions().setInsecureSSL(true)
- Using the IP address in the URL instead of the DNS name

I want to eventually run this test on Jenkins, so have tried various HTTPS proxy and port settings on Jenkins to no prevail. If anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be because of SSL handshake or JavaScript error. Do you have other exceptions? You need to provide more details, for others to reproduce it.

Comment: HtmlUnit does not use the usual proxy setting of the JVM. Have a look at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html on how to configure your proxy.

Comment: There aren't any other exceptions, there doesn't appear to be any thrown and caught anywhere else. As regards to the proxy setting, a HTTP URL works with the current settings, it's only with HTTPS. Would this make a different to what you were suggesting RBRi?

Comment: Sounds strange. Any option to do a test with HtmlUnit only (like the simple first example on page http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html?

Comment: There should be no difference between http and https from the proxy settings

Comment: Perhaps there is another reason why the webpage isn't loading then.